# Ошибка при валидации маски ввода номера телефона

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, yii2

На сайте используется yii2, В форме для валидации номера телефона подключён плагин `jquery.maskedinput.min.js`.
Подключение к полю ввода примерно такое:

```
$("#order-delivery_phone").mask("+380(999) 999-9999");
```

Само моле выводится так:

```
<?=$form->field($model, 'delivery_phone')->label(false)->error(false)->input('tel', ['class' => 'orderForm-sidebar__input', 'placeholder' => Yii::t('web', 'Телефон').'*', 'required' => ''])?>
```

но проблема в том, что после ввода номера, и когда курсор отводится с этого поля, т.е. когда происходит событие `blur` с данного поля ввода, то к данному полю добавляется класс `has-error`, и поле подсвечивается красным, т.е. скорее всего встроенному валидатору не нравится приставка +380.
А если сделать такую маску:

```
$("#order-delivery_phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
```

то данный класс ошибки не добавляется, и валидация данного поля проходит нормально.
Подскажите, как избежать данной ошибки при валидации номера телефона?
Может нужно как-то отключить валидацию для номера телефона?  Только где это можно сделать?

Comment: дак как тут по вашему `380` к маске относится? вот 9 это а-ля `\d`, то есть произвольное число.

Comment: @teran, нужно сделать такую маску: `+380...`, т.е. чтобы при фокусе появлялась приставка `+380...`. Как тогда нужно сделать правильно?

Comment: @Yaroslav Molchan, вы не поняли вопрос

Comment: решил проблему. нужно было увеличить длину поля ввода для телефона ` ['delivery_phone'], 'string', 'max' => 18],` в файле Order.php

Answer (score -1):

Пример на  [CodeOpen](https://codepen.io/SweetTomato/pen/qnLcJ). Работает с такой маской `$("#phone").mask("+380 (999) 999-9999");`

Comment: при чём здесь работает с такой маской? Я выше писал, что у меня с такой маской появляется класс `has-error`

Comment: Так выполните поиск "has-error" по коду и посмотрите где он добавляется и почему.